# Chart Behavior in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a time-series data in my table. Sample Data given below:

```
+------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| CODE | YEAR_MONTH | CALC_LVL1 | CALC_LVL2 | MSRMT_PCT_1 | MSRMT_PCT_2 |
+------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| A1   |     201912 |        87 |       564 |        0.14 |         0.1 |
| A1   |     201911 |        34 |       455 |        0.15 |        0.08 |
| A1   |     201910 |        20 |       295 |         0.1 |        0.14 |
| A1   |     201909 |        39 |       219 |        0.08 |        0.14 |
| A1   |     201908 |        98 |       438 |        0.14 |        0.11 |
| A1   |     201907 |         7 |       219 |        0.08 |        0.14 |
| A1   |     201812 |        63 |       564 |        0.14 |        0.17 |
| A1   |     201808 |        12 |       455 |        0.15 |        0.13 |
| A1   |     201805 |        48 |       409 |        0.13 |        0.13 |
| A1   |     201802 |        88 |       289 |        0.11 |        0.08 |
| A1   |     201801 |         9 |       492 |        0.14 |        0.13 |
+------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Is there any way that the default chart shows me the year values, and when user clicks on a year label, then it shows monthly data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are looking for Time Axis chart where the chart label is mapped to the DATE or TIMESTAMP column. In the chart attributes, set the Time Axis Type to Enabled. Labels will then be correctly rendered as readable dates. You can then build another chart or report that can be drilled down from this chart. To do this, navigate to the chart, select the series and then in the property editor, navigate to Column Mapping. Select the column names for LABEL and VALUE. For Link > Type, select Redirect to Page in this application. Click Target, select the page and set page item and value.